# static font not applied in tailwind

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

i am using tailwind css + next js. i am unable to import static font from /fonts/rubik.woff2 file

```
//gobals.css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@fontface {
  font-family: "rubik";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: fallback;
  src: url(/fonts/rubik.woff2) format("woff2");
}
```

```
//tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    FontFace: {},
    fontFamily: {
      home: ["rubik", "cursive"],
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

sandBox:- https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-frost-ujdocz?file=/src/styles.css

I have tried almost everything in my knowledge but i am unable to make it work. The project file structure

[image: file structure]

Comment: Open network tab in dev tools and check if the font loads

Comment: no they are not loading even if I am disabling local fonts

Comment: So the path is wrong

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P1u8_pq4tajZMZtDBwcZP7PDZwSUTsej/view?usp=sharing my file strcture

Comment: tell me what it is? from photo

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1INxjDOa0v8LPkMh3WIv7kFpfFVcUXHDB/view?usp=sharing network tab look like this

Comment: i am sure i am using correct path because if i am using wrong path next js giving me error

Comment: hi are you here ?

Comment: Move `/fonts/rubik.woff2` inside the `public` folder, that's where `url("/fonts/rubik.woff2")` is trying to get the font from. See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving. Alternatively, if you don't want the font in `public` change the path to `url("../fonts/rubik.woff2")`.

Answer (score 1):

Below are the steps you can follow, have created a StackBlitz example https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-9aq3v4-ozdwn4?file=styles%2Fglobals.css

1. Extend your tailwind theme in `tailwind.config.js`

```js
 theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        Rubik: ['Rubik'],
      },
    },
  },
```

2. Copy the fonts at the root level
   [image]
3. Import the font correctly in the `styles/golbals.css`

```scss
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Rubik';
  src: url('../fonts/Rubik-Regular.ttf');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

4. Use the font

```
 <h1 className="text-6xl font-Rubik">
Hello
</h1>
```

Comment: still not working

Comment: Did you try forking this https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-9aq3v4-ozdwn4